# How to remove shadow below NavigationView?

Tags: android, android-layout

If the height of a `NavigationView` is less than the height of its parent, there's a drop shadow below the `NavigationView`.  How can I remove that shadow?

Here's my layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@android:color/white">

    <android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/map_type_menu"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_map_type"/>

    <!-- unwanted drop shadow here -->

    <fragment
            android:id="@+id/settings"
            android:name="com.chalcodes.treasuremap.SettingsFragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image]

I don't think this is relevant, but here's the `menu_map_type` XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <group android:checkableBehavior="single">
        <item
                android:id="@+id/item_street"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_map_type_street"
                android:title="@string/map_type_street" />
        <item
                android:id="@+id/item_satellite"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_map_type_satellite"
                android:title="@string/map_type_satellite" />
        <item
                android:id="@+id/item_hybrid"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_map_type_satellite"
                android:title="@string/map_type_hybrid" />

        <item
                android:id="@+id/item_terrain"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_menu_map_type_terrain"
                android:title="@string/map_type_terrain" />
    </group>

</menu>
```

Comment: can I see your design screenshot ?

Comment: can you paste the code of `menu_map_type` file ?

Comment: I have tried. but I not finding your solution of this type. Sorry

Answer (score 9):

Just add to your NavigationView layout:

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

Comment: On API 23 and higher I have encountered a problem: when setting `app:elevation="0dp"`, there's a grayish tint over `NavigationView`. The solution would be setting `NavigationView` another attribute: `android:background="#0000"`

Answer (score 1):

The shadow is caused by the `NavigationView` having a non-zero default elevation.  This was actually the first thing I thought of, but the way I tried to change it didn't work, so I mistakenly thought elevation wasn't the problem.

I originally added `android:elevation="0dp"` in the `NavigationView` declaration.  This produced a warning because I'm supporting APIs below 21.  I incorrectly assumed that this attribute would remain effective for API 21+, but apparently it gets stripped.

The solution was to set the elevation in code:

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    navView.setElevation(0f);
}
```

Comment: `I incorrectly assumed that this attribute would remain effective for API 21+, but apparently it gets stripped.` Cannot believe that can happen.

Comment: @azizbekian Whatever the reason, `android:elevation="0dp"` has no effect.

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
<android.support.design.widget.NavigationView
            android:id="@+id/map_type_menu"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            app:menu="@menu/menu_map_type">


 <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent" android:orientation="vertical"> 

<include layout="@layout/nav_header" /> 

<fragment android:id="@+id/settings" android:name="com.chalcodes.treasuremap.SettingsFragment" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout> 

</android.support.design.widget.NavigationView>
```

Comment: The height cannot be `match_parent`.  The `NavigationView` shares its parent with other views.

Comment: I was wrong. Could you please post a screenshot? It's hard to guess where that shadow would be?

Comment: Added a screenshot.

Comment: Updated the solution.

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a way to position a child directly below the `NavigationView` menu items.  Too bad `NavigationView` extends `FrameLayout` instead of `RelativeLayout`.